# How can I get a specific object of specific type from list of objects in Cpp

Tags: c++, design-patterns

I have an animal manager class that has a list of object that implement the IAnimal interface. It has a method that must get the cats only from that same list. How can i design my code in a better way to achieve this ?

Sample code below (in C++)

```
#include<iostream>
#include<list>

class IAnimal
{
    void doSomeThing();
};

class Cat : public IAnimal
{
    void doSomeThing()
    {
        std::cout << "Cat" << std::endl;
    }
};

class Dog : public IAnimal
{
    void doSomeThing()
    {
        std::cout << "Dog" << std::endl;
    }
};

class AnimalManager
{
    private:
    std::list<IAnimal> animals;

    public:
    void manageCat()
    {
     //get cats from animals list.
    }
};
```

Comment: Couple of problems which need fixing before the question is answered. The first is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing

Comment: I would guess the OP is more familiar with Java, just something about the language used.

Comment: If your manager needs to know that "something" is a cat, the design is broken. If you want to do something, which is specific to a cat, you should provide that details inside the cat class. If you spread the details of the behavior of cat to different places of implementation, you violate important design principals. If you really want to continue your way: Provide a method to all classes like "getCatOnly()" and make it returns INVALID or a pointer or ref only for the cat class. But again: Please don't do it. You may also think about std::variant which is a totally different approach.

Comment: BTW: `std::list<IAnimal> animals;` will not work! This will slice all your objects down to the type of IAnimal and you don't have any cats and docs anymore :-)

Comment: @Klaus "...If you manager needs to know that "something" is a cat, the design is broken...", what is the best way to achieve this then ?

Comment: (1) This can’t work without the `virtual` keyword. (2) The `std::list` of animals must contain pointers (e.g. `std::unique_ptr<IAnimal>`) to the superclass, not the superclass instances themselves, or else *slicing* will occur instead of late binding. You can make `IAnimal` purely virtual to avoid slicing mistakes (`virtual void doSomething() = 0;`). (3) To select (filter out) `Cat`s, either [ugly approach] introduce a virtual method `isCat()` that returns `false` by default and is overridden in `Cat` or [better approach] introduce a virtual method `species()` returning suitable `enum` values.

Comment: @AndrejPodzimek would dynamic_cast work here? (given that slicing is taken care of first)

Comment: In C++, unlike Java or C#, normally declared objects (as opposed to dynamically-allocated objects) are not references by default; they are what in C# parlance are called 'value types'. In order to use them as you mean to, you need to use pointers to the objects, rather than the objects themselves. Otherwise, the objects in the list would devolve to the base type ('class slicing'), even if the value assigned to them is of the derived type.

Comment: Oh also because I haven't seem anyone else mention it yet, a discriminated union would work (but would make all the subtyping useless). Also runtime type magic generally means you are doing something very wrong

Comment: Note that C++ doesn't have interfaces as a design concept; rather, C++ supports multiple inheritance, which works significantly differently from interfaces in either Java or C#.

Comment: @DownloadPizza Yes, kind of. You could do something like `for (const auto &animal_ptr : animals) { try { auto &cat{dynamic_cast<Cat&>(*animal_ptr)}; /* yes, it is a cat */ cat.doSomething(); ...; } catch (const std::bad_cast &) { /* no, it is not a cat, so we ignore it */ } }`. But this is ugly … to say the least.

Comment: @DownloadPizza Re: _"I haven't seem anyone else mention it yet, ..."_ - Klaus mentioned `std::variant` which is the modern way to do `union` stuff.

Comment: @AndrejPodzimek if you use pointers instead of references you don't need a try catch

Comment: @DownloadPizza Yes, indeed, but [this difference](https://pastebin.com/VHiK2G3B) is (IMHO) a very unfortunate part of the C++ standard. You don’t need a `try` / `catch` with pointers, but you don’t gain much either, because you have to explicitly check for null pointers. So there’s no readability or brevity benefit and when it comes to maintainability, a switch to/from pointers/references can yield either exceptions or null pointers popping up in code that previously worked and passed `valgrind` just fine.